# What does it depend on, whether you can or cannot call a Java getter/setter method using Kotlin's property access syntax, in one case or another?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In some cases you are able to use property access syntax to reference Java getters/setters, in some cases you aren't. What defines this behaviour?

```kotlin
val tv = TextView(this)
tv.setText("") // WEAK WARNING: Use of setter method instead of property access syntax
tv.text = "" // OK

val iv = ImageView(this)
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) // no weak warning, meant to be used that way
iv.imageResource = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background // ERROR: Unresolved reference: imageResource
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only creates a property if it can find a getter and setter with matching type. In your ImageView example, there's a `setImageReference` but no `getImageReference`, so no property.

Another example would be with TextView. You can do

```kotlin
textView.text = "hello"
```

but you cannot do

```kotlin
textView.text = R.string.hello // have to use textView.setText(R.string.hello)
```

This is because `TextView.getText()` returns a CharSequence so the only `setText` overload that matches is the one that takes a CharSequence argument.

Comment: Wonderful! It's so clear now!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

> Note that, if the Java class only has a setter, it isn't visible as a property in Kotlin because Kotlin doesn't support set-only properties.

`ImageView` has a `setImageResource` but no `getImageResource`, so it falls into the category mentioned above.